# how treat the database record that are not activated or how to prevent it

Tags: mysql, web

we have a user table to record all the user that is sign up in our website,
but some might not activate it

our practice for now is once user register, a record will store in our table, once the user click the activation link, the activation code will change to ' ' (empty)

if the record did not activated, the email can't be use and will always in our table

```
user
id | email       | activation code
1  | abc@abc.com |asdasdasdadadsasda
2  | cde@abc.com |
```

whats the best practice or solution for this?

create a new table to store all the activation code and only insert into user table once they activated?

or just leave it like that? but there is a waste to store it

or any better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I used to do it this way:

- a temporary table containing temporary accounts (not yet activated)
- a table containing accounts (activated)

Thanks to this, you can spare some spaces in your main account table and you can also add a task (for example, each week) that will remove old temporary accounts.

When a user activates his account, you move its data from temporary to main table.

Answer (score 0):

**A solution in nutshell:**

Add a column to the `User` table: `is_activated TINYINT(1)` with `DEFAULT 0`

Create a table for the activation codes:

```
user_id, activation_code, created_at, valid_to
```

When a user registers, insert the activation code into the new table, then insert the user into the users table with `is_activated = 0`.

When a user activates it's account, delete the activation code and update the `is_activated` to `1` for the user.

Create a cronjob which runs periodicaly and checks for invalid (expired) activation codes (`valid_to < NOW()`).

- Delete all users which are not activated and their activation code is expired.
- Delete all activation codes where the user not exists for the code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing link, keep a flag represents true or false. Make it true If account gets activated.